# Problems installing the Ultimate Vault Hunters pack with season pass

Tags: borderlands-2

I bought the season pass for BL2. I can see all of the other DLCs that have installed but I do not see the "Borderlands 2: Ultimate Vault Hunters Upgrade Pack" that has the level cap increase. Can someone tell me how to figure out if it installed?

Comment: I looked and I'm not sure I saw it either...one way to tell would of course be to see if you can gain XP past level 50. I'll check and see if it shows listed with the other DLC tonight.

Comment: The downside is I picked up the game late and am only 45

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it seems there *is* no visual indication if you only own the Season Pass:

[image]

However my BL2 did update and I quite certainly have been able to level over 50. So I would say as long as your BL2 has updated since the patch (April 2nd) and you own the Season Pass your Ultimate Vault Hunters Pack should be active.

Comment: I would have upvoted the answer as well... but I have to have 15 rep :/

Answer (score 1):

- First way to fix is to dashboard and start up the game again. The game will then check for downloaded content and make it work.
- Second way is to try and reinstall each download. Sometimes downloads will go contradict each other. This may be one of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I swear I remember seeing it in the list right after I installed it, but when I look at the list now, it isn't there. I would assume that it's installed on your game.

Comment: I have something called the "premier club;" but, everything else named does not say "Ult Vault Hunter Pack." Everything says that it is included in the season pass. Might it not be showing up because I haven't hit 50?

Comment: Well, that's odd... I know it was visible the other night, but I don't see it anymore. Reversing my answer...

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try downloading it straight from the store instead of loading the game and download it that what I did but I'm on psn but for xbox try the same it should work too

Answer (score -1):

from what I readyou have to start the game from the beginningand then it just gives younew levels and better chances to get better guns